# Синхронизация СУБД MongoDB и Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, firebase

Есть два приложения. У обоих сервер на Node.js, клиент на Vue.js. Одно использует в качестве БД MongoDB второе  Firebase. Поставлена задача чтобы оба приложения оперировали одними и теми же данными. Сильно много переделывать не хочется, хочется пойти так сказать по пути наименьшего сопротивления. 
Как проще сделать? Сделать им одну общую БД или синхронизировать две уже существующие, которые они используют? 
И вообще можно ли синхронизировать MongoDB и Firebase? Если вариант рабочий, не могли бы поделиться ссылками на примеры?